# Visual Studio 2008: after adding Smart Device (Windows CE) project the device emulator shows up every time

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, projects-and-solutions

I've got a pretty big solution with lots of projects. Until now everything worked fine. After adding a Smart Device project it always starts the device emulator selection dialog, even when starting other projects (which don't need the smart device emulator).

Any ideas how to disable this emulator (as it takes some time until it comes up) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the Configuartion Manager and uncheck "Deploy" for the Smart Device application.

Answer (score 1):

okay - now I found a way to circumvent this.

I have to unload the smart device project. Then everything works fine.